# Modifying format of individual characters per cell per range based on capitalization. Excel random errors

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to make an Acronym list for work. First column list the acronym. Second column spells out the acronym while keeping the main components capitalized.

Ex. | POC | Point Of Contact |

Goal is to format the capitalized characters for easier viewing by making them bold, increasing the size, and changing the color to red.

Ex. | POC | **P**oint **O**f **C**ontact | ------------*imagine letters are red and bigger*

Since I have 1,000+ acronyms to deal with I created a VBA code to check each character per cell and format the correct ones. Below you can find my code.

Excel can handle some phrases fine while choking then crashing on others. I've tried to check for patterns as to why without any luck.

Other times Excel will act in unpredictable ways such as duplicating the leading letter or highlighting the rest of the phrase red. When comparing the text value in the formula bar vs what's visible in the cell, one can see a difference

Example of error

[image: Example of error]

These troubled cells have a tendency to corrupt the file if saved and re-opened.

Is there something inherently wrong with my code, or is Excel just being buggy for some reason? Would there be a different way to do this without causing excel to have bugs and corrupt the file?

**UPDATE: Another Example of Error Running the suggested code**

[image: 2nd Example]

```
Sub Acronym_List_Formatting()
Dim cll As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim q As Integer
Dim Char As String
Dim UChar As String
Dim Phrase() As String

q = Application.InputBox("Set the base font size", Default:=12, Type:=1)

'| Set initial formatting of everything |'

With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = q
    .Bold = False
    .Color = vbBlack
End With

'| Main Code |'

For Each cll In Selection

ReDim Phrase(Len(cll.Value))

 For i = 1 To Len(cll.Value)

    Char = Mid$(cll.Value, i, 1)
    UChar = UCase$(Char)
    Phrase(i) = Char

   If Asc(UChar) >= 65 And Asc(UChar) <= 90 Then '|Asc returns the ASCII value ; Continues only if character is a letter|'

        If Char = UChar Then
            With cll.Characters(i, 1).Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Size = .Size + 1.5
                    .Color = vbRed
            End With

        End If

   End If

   Next i

 'Debug.Print "Phrase: " & Join(Phrase)
 MsgBox ("Phrase: " & Join(Phrase, ""))

 Next cll

 End Sub
```

**UPDATE(2): An excerpt of my data for testing**

Amcom[aviation and missile command] Engineering Directorate

c2BmC[command and control, battle management and communication] element lead

Bmds[ballistic missile defense system] Opir[overhead persistent infrared] Architecture

Jtids[joint tactical information distribution system] Interface Control

Nato[north atlantic treaty organization] General Communications System

Osf[objective simulation framework] Public Interface

Patriot[phased array tracking radar intercept on target] Advanced Capability 3 SIMulation

Patriot[phased array tracking radar intercept on target] Anti‐Cruise Missile

Patriot[phased array tracking radar intercept on target] Conduct Of Fire Trainer

RW[] Integrated ToolSet

Sm‐3[standard missile‐3] Cooperative Development

SPAWAR[Space & Naval Warfare Systems Command] Systems Center PACIFIC

THaad[terminal high altitude area defense] element lead

Comment: Can you poinpoint this by stepping through the code with `F8`? That may help you see where it's getting wonky.

Comment: I've tried going through it using F8. What its doing doesn't match whats going on in the code. One time I went through it using F8 and it worked, but then I reset the formatting and tried again just running the code all at once and the same error occurred. Wierd

Comment: The first thing that you need to do is to make sure that your Excel sheet's codebase isn't corrupted.  The easiest way I know to do that is to download the VBA Code Cleaner from here (http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) and use it (export everything, then re-import it).  If that doesn't fix your problems, then I would recommend re-installing Excel/Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to identify and format upper case letters you can use this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AcronymListFormatting()
    Dim fntSz As Variant, cll As Range, i As Long, char As String

    fntSz = Application.InputBox("Set the base font size", Default:=12, Type:=1)

    If fntSz <> False And fntSz > 7 Then    'validate user input and Cancel
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = fntSz
            .Bold = False
            .Color = vbBlack
        End With
        For Each cll In Selection.Cells
            For i = 1 To Len(cll.Value2)
                char = Mid$(cll.Value2, i, 1)
                If Asc(char) >= 65 And Asc(char) <= 90 Then    'A-Z = 65-90, a-z = 97-122
                    With cll.Characters(i, 1).Font
                        .Bold = True
                        .Size = .Size + 1.5
                        .Color = vbRed
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

[image: Result]

---

To convert to proper case:

```
cll.Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cll.Value2)
```

or

```
cll.Value2 = StrConv(cll.Value2, vbProperCase)
```

---

**Edit 1**

Testing with new data:

[image: NewData]

**Edit 2**

The issues (random errors) were caused by corrupt text imported from external file, as seen in P. McInturff's comment bellow

Comment: I appreciate your condensed version of my code. It runs a lot faster than mine does. However, I am still getting similar errors when it is run: duplication of capital letter, converting the rest of the phrase to red, even inputting random characters. I have uploaded another example image running your code in my post

Comment: Added the text. Have Fun!

Comment: There is something strange going on with your machine: I tried the text and it's being highlighted as expected (see the new image). Not only that, but I tested your code too and it's working fine (slower, but fine). Do you have any strange fonts installed? or maybe a problem with the Office install, antivirus, other input capture programs or utilities installed? In your place, I would step through the code line by line (press F8 in the VBA editor) and inspect each variable as the code executes to try to determine what ASCII characters are being processed

Comment: Pay attention to the text "Engineering Directorate" - the capital E is where the first problem starts. Also, try copying the text from the browser window (the way I did it) - maybe there is something corrupt in your file, or just create a new one from scratch just for testing...

Comment: I tried coping the text from the browser window, That worked. I went back to my main document, copied all text, pasted it into notepad, then recopied/pasted it into a new excel spreadsheet. After running the code it worked perfectly. There must have been something wrong with the file. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found the issue